# How to update "sorting_order" column of other rows when changing one?

Tags: mysql, update, php, sorting

I need to set a custom order sequence for categories when adding new ones, and changing existing ones. I believe the code and sql query will be the same in both scenarios.
In my `webshop_categories`-table I have a `so`-column (sorting order INT) that I uses to determen which order the categories should be outputed to the viewer.

Here's a simplified example of how my categories-table looks like (so = sorting_order):

```
id  |   name   |  so
--------------------
1   |   Shoes  |  1
2   |   Hats   |  2
3   |   Bags   |  3
4   |   Coats  |  4
5   |   Rings  |  5
```

When adding a new category, without defining the sorting order, I would just submit a form, and run a query like this:

```
$so = $dbh->query('SELECT (MAX(so)+1) FROM webshop_categories WHERE so != 0')->fetchColumn();
$ins = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO webshop_categories (name, so)')->execute([$_POST['name'], $so]);
```

*(This will add a new category, and just put it at the end. In this case the `so` would be set to 6)*

That's the very basic way of just adding a new category. Works fine. But in most cases, when dealing with categories, one need to put it in a specific order for presentation.

But usually when adding a new category, one would want to specify where this new category should be placed in relation to the existing ones. And that's when updating the `so`-column becomes a brain twister for me...

My simplified form for adding a new category:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <select name="so">
    <option value="0" selected>At the end</option>
    <option value="1">At the top</option>
    <!-- php foreach loop through exising categories -->
    <option value="<?=so?>">after <?=category_name?></option>
  <select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_add" value="Add">
</form>

<?php
if($_POST['submit_add']){
  if($_POST['so']==0){  //  put new category at the end
    $so = $dbh->query('SELECT (MAX(so)+1) FROM webshop_categories WHERE so != 0')->fetchColumn();
  } else {
    $so = $_POST['so'];
  }
  $ins = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO webshop_categories (name, so)')->execute([$_POST['name'], $so]);
}
?>
```

I've been through the first scenario: Not specifying a sorting order.
But when it comes to using this feature, I need to update the `so` for the affected categories.
If I add a new category between Shoes and Hats I would use *after Shoes* in the selection list - which means that this new category should get the `so`-value of **2**. This means that it will be necessary to do a `+1` to the `so` for Hats and all categories above.

What would be a good way of accomplishing this?

A quite equal situation to this would be when moving a category from a higher to a lower `so` number. One would need to make space for the moved category, and bump the rest one up (do a `+1` to their `so`). But only the ones in between the two positions ofcourse.

And it should be quite similar when doing it the other way around - Moving a category from a lower to a higher number. The only difference being that we now need to close the gap that we created between these two powitions.
If I moved Hats to `after Coats` - Hats would become 4, and the rest would need to be bumped one down (do a `-1` to their `so`).

I've tried to do this by fetching the affected categories when using this feature, and update each one in a foreach loop. But I couldnt get it to work as expected for all scenarios.

Making a Copy of the all the rows (into a PHP array), Delete them, Create a new list with updated so, then Inserting them back was also a solution, but I dont think it should be neccesary just to make these changes... But that's one way I figured out that worked...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Add new category :**

```
    $t_cat = 'jeans';//new category to insert
    $so_to_set = 2;// so for new category
```

First update all `so` greater than or equal to `$so_to_set`

```
    $query = "update categaries set so = so+1 where so >= $so_to_set";
```

Now insert new `category` with the `$so_to_set`

```
    $query = "insert into categaries(name,so) values($t_cat,$so_to_set)";
```

**Change `so` for categories :**

suppose we have following `categaries` with `so`

```
    +-------------------------+
    | id  |   name    | so    |
    +-----+-----------+-------+
    | 1   |   shoes   |  1    |
    | 6   |   jeans   |  2    |
    | 2   |   shirts  |  3    |
    | 3   |   pants   |  4    |
    | 4   |   blazzers|  5    |
    | 5   |   bags    |  6    |
    +-------------------------+

    $a = 2;// so of category whose position we want to change
    $b = 5;// new so for category

    // get id of category whose position we want to change
    $temp_id = "select id from categaries where so = $a"; 
    // that would be 6
```

Now update all so between `$a` and `$b`

```
    if($a < $b){
        // if $a is less than $b then
        $set = "so = so - 1";
        $where = "so > $a and so <= $b";
    }else{
        $set = "so = so + 1";
        $where = "so < $a and so >= $b";
    }

    // update so's
    $query = "update categaries set $set where $where";
```

now update so for `$temp_id`

```
    $query = "update categaries set so = $b where id = $temp_id";
```

Final output of the process would be

```
    +-------------------------+
    | id  |   name    | so    |
    +-----+-----------+-------+
    | 1   |   shoes   |  1    |
    | 6   |   jeans   |  5    |
    | 2   |   shirts  |  2    |
    | 3   |   pants   |  3    |
    | 4   |   blazzers|  4    |
    | 5   |   bags    |  6    |
    +-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Ordering should be performed with step greater than one. I prefer the step equal to 10 for better visual representation. Main idea that new item always can be inserted with SO=N+1 that is normally unused. Say, you have inserted something in between 30 and 40, then your `so` sequence now look like that: 10-20-30-31-40-50.

Then you have to `UPDATE` the table that way:

```
SET @cnt = 0;
UPDATE table AS w
   SET w.so = @cnt := @cnt + 10
 ORDER BY w.so ASC
;
```

The result of `UPDATE` is that `so` field is filled by evenly distributed numbers with step of 10: 10-20-30-40-50-60. Now 31 becomes 40, 40 becomes 50 and so forth.

Indeed it is better to incapsulate all the insertion/renumeration into the `START TRANSACTION .. COMMIT;` for sake of data consistency. Two simultaneous `INSERTS` with the same `so`=N+1 can drive to problems. Also an `UNIQUE` index is recommended for `so` field.

Later when you fetch the data from the table you have to divide `so` values by 10 to get the plain sequence of the natural numbers:

```
SELECT w.so / 10 AS so
     , ... 
  FROM table AS w
 ORDER BY w.so
;
```